# How to convert certificate in .pem format from .crt files..?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have 4ec7049585ebc7.crt and gd_bundle.crt files. I want to convert it into pem format. I need two files one certificate and key in pem format. what is the openssl command for it.?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Paul Heinlein's [OpenSSL Command-Line HOWTO](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/). Its got lots of recipes.

Do you know what format the files are currently in? They are probably already in PEM format. If not, you can simply try `-inform ASN1`, `-inform PEM`, etc until you find something that does not error.

More than likely, you are going to have to breakout `gd_bundle.crt` with a script because its going to be full of PEM encoded certificates concatenated together.

Comment: I followed steps shown in below link, Then it works.

<a href="http://answers.splunk.com/answers/1899/how-do-i-use-intermediate-ssl-chain-certs-on-splunk">http://answers.splunk.com/answers/1899/how-do-i-use-intermediate-ssl-chain-certs-on-splunk </a>